# due to lightdm-gtk-greeter's broken permissions, user wallpaper is not shown

Tags: permissions, login, lightdm, desktop-background

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.03 32 bit platform.
The day before while installing udev from source it messed up permissions in my system. I fixed some of the permissions and I managed to login. I noticed that user wallpaper is not set in login screen. I reinstalled lightdm and lightdm-gtk-greeter but it doesn't work. in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` if I set `background=` path manually it shows wallpaper but when I change user wallpaper it doesn't sync walpaper in login screen.

I tested lightdm with `lightdm --test-mode --debug`

```
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /home/kenn/.cache/lightdm/log/lightdm.log
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.10.5, UID=1000 PID=4414
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-gnome.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/gnome/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/gnome-cairo-dock/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/xdg-gnome-cairo-dock/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Running in user mode
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
 [+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module surfaceflinger
 [+0.04s] WARNING: Failed to get list of logind seats: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.login1 was not provided by any .service files
 [+0.04s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
 [+0.04s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting
 [+0.04s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
 [+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
 [+0.04s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1002 added
 [+0.05s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1004 added
 [+0.06s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
 [+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1003 added
 [+0.10s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 added
 [+0.11s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
 [+0.11s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display
 [+0.11s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /home/kenn/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1.log
 [+0.11s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Writing X server authority to /home/kenn/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
 [+0.15s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Launching X Server
 [+0.15s] DEBUG: Launching process 4418: /usr/bin/Xephyr :1 -seat seat0 -auth /home/kenn/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1 -nolisten tcp
 [+0.15s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
 [+0.16s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
 [+0.16s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
 [+0.56s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 4418
 [+0.56s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Got signal from X server :1
 [+0.56s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Connecting to XServer :1
 [+0.57s] DEBUG: Launching process 4424: play-sound /home/kenn/Documents/The_Best_windows_startup_sound_Ever___.mp3
 [+0.59s] DEBUG: Process 4424 exited with return value 0
 [+0.59s] DEBUG: Seat: Exit status of play-sound /home/kenn/Documents/The_Best_windows_startup_sound_Ever___.mp3: 0
 [+0.60s] DEBUG: Seat: Display server ready, starting session authentication
 [+0.60s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
 [+0.60s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'kenn'
 Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
 W: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to open configuration file '//.config/pulse//daemon.conf': Permission denied
 W: [pulseaudio] daemon-conf.c: Failed to open configuration file: Permission denied
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Seat: Session authenticated, running command
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Not setting XDG_VTNR
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/lightdm-gtk-greeter
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/kenn
 [+0.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Logging to /home/kenn/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1-greeter.log
 [+1.16s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Greeter connected version=1.10.5
 [+2.10s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Greeter start authentication for kenn
 [+2.10s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
 [+2.10s] DEBUG: Session pid=4470: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'kenn'
 [+2.29s] DEBUG: Session pid=4470: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
 [+2.29s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: Authenticate result for user kenn: Success
 [+2.29s] DEBUG: Session pid=4426: User kenn authorized
```

I also noticed that power options such as `shutdown, reboot, hibernate..` is not active on lightdm
How can I fix it?